# SQLiteMetro Group by

Tags: sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Is Group by clause supported by this lib?

I wrote query Select SectionName, DepartmentName, SUM(SalesValue) FROM ( SELECT SectionName, Date, DepartmentName, SalesValue FROM StockDaily join Section on StockDaily.idSection=Section._id join Department on StockDaily.idDepartment = Department._id where idStore=1 and Date >=" + '"' + from + '"' + "and Date <=" + '"' + to + '"' + ")"+" Group by SectionName

It works in sqlite manager but in cod with lib not:/ Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try editing your question to be a self contained example.  You should also ask it in the simplest way possible, ie no nested queiries and variable substitution.  I tried fixing the formatting to be readable, but I can't even tell what you're trying to do.  The quotes don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sqlite supports `GROUP BY` aggregation.  Here is the [reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).